# Can't get VGA monitor to display anything with passive adapter

Tags: raspbian, display

I have an old monitor that only takes VGA, a passive adapter from HDMI to VGA and a Raspberry Pi B with the most recent version of Raspbian. I followed this guide: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/three-ways-to-display-your-raspberry-pi-on-a-monitor-or-tv/, and it asks me to add a couple of lines to the config.txt. The file did not exist so I created it, and you can see the content below:

```
jdoe@jdoe:/media/jdoe/sdcard/boot$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35 Jun 26 12:19 config.txt
jdoe@jdoe:/media/jdoe/sdcard/boot$ cat config.txt 
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

I've checked the monitor with another computer, and it does work.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You've checked to make sure the monitor works, but have you checked if the adapter works? You can try this with another computer with HDMI out and the same monitor (since you've made sure it works).

Comment: I did check that :)

Comment: This is probably a duplicate. It is a common question. I thought I had answered it before, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/boot` directory on the second, larger, ext4 formatted partition is a mount point for the first, smaller, VFAT partition *when the system is running*.

So, if you stick the SD card in another computer and look in `/boot` on the second partition, there should be nothing there. If there is, it won't serve any purpose as it will be hidden and inaccessible underneath the mounted filesystem once the system boots.  In case this isn't clear: don't bother to put anything there.

The `config.txt` you are looking for **does exist**, but it is on that first partition, not the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The rpi does non work with vga and passive adaptors! You must use an active one.